# How do I make a function that reads a csv, converts its lists into dictionaries to result in a certain output in python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

A csv file in python which includes a list of integers and string such as:

`Sunset,61,South,2002-12-28,48,3,25,168,42,13`

`Sunrise,42,North,2012-02-05,84,3,39,141,13,115`

How would I make a function which would, open and read the csv, convert it into a dictionary (in this case would be named **dict**) so that I could put in an input like this in the function:

`sun_state(dict, 61)`

and get an output of:

`[ '2002-12-28', '84', '4', '49', '308']`

the format of the output follows respectively:

The date, three integers after the date and the sum of the last three integers.

If I had made any problems with my question, please do tell, I would love the help of any kind, thank you.

Comment: First, do not name your object `dict`.  That's the name of the dictionary type in Python, and you would be hiding the standard meaning.  Second, you don't really want your numeric values to be strings, do you?  You have them in quotes.  Finally, why would "61" produce those values?  You're pulling from both rows.  It doesn't make sense.  Where does the "4" come from?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply read a **csv** file by using pandas and create a dictionary (although I could not understand your output given your explanation) as follows:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv("data/id_to_date.csv", header=None, names=["Sunset","ID","Direction","Date","col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6"])
    sun_dict = {}
    for row_id, row in df.iterrows():
        values = [row["Date"], row["col1"], row["col2"], row["col3"], sum([row["col4"], row["col5"], row["col6"]])] 
        sun_dict[row["ID"]] = values
    print(sun_dict[61])
```

Result:

```
['2002-12-28', 48, 3, 25, 223]
```